# Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDouble' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'. at AsBooleanGetter(Object )

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I have this section of code:

```
public List<BsonDocument> ReturnAllTripNumbers()
    {
        var collection = MongoDbContext.Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(TRIPS_COLLECTION);

        var result = collection.Find(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty)
            .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
                    .Include("tripNumber")
                    .Include("registry")
                    .Include("clientName")
                    .Include("accountNumber")
                    .Exclude("_id"));

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

And 4 fields are returned as expected for every item in the collection, the issue is that when everything finishes and at the end of controller i have Ok(result) instead of returning all those results it gives me: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDouble' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'. at AsBooleanGetter(Object ) error

Comment: Since you say this method `ReturnAllTripNumbers()` is fine, I think you should share the controller code which triggers the error for [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Did you perform the mapping from BsonDocument to class?

Comment: @YongShun Where would I map that ? I receive around 200 results but it fails only when the result is supposed to be returned